# How to run cron job in cpanel

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

my cron job path is

> http://example.com/beta/cron/reportData

added this url in cron job but email return me "No such file or directory".
How to resolve this issue please help me.

Comment: I think you had to give relative path of the file rather than absolute path.

Comment: same issue."No such file or directory"

Comment: Refer this   http://serverfault.com/questions/401311/why-is-crontab-giving-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-the-file-does-exist

Comment: Finally run my cron job :) use `wget mysite.org/admin/sendDailyEmail` thanks for @doitlikejustin

Answer (score 0):

Use `curl -s -o /dev/null` before `;)`